# In Spring MVC mapped method not getting called when requestparam is not present in post

Tags: post, spring-mvc

I have three request param in my method and only if Http POST request body has all three parameters `availableCostTypesReturn,selectedCostTypesReturn and costTypeProgramId` then only this method is getting called.

Successful POST request Body

```
 availableCostTypesReturn=1&availableCostTypesReturn=2&availableCostTypesReturn=3&
 availableCostTypesReturn=4&selectedCostTypesReturn=5&costTypeProgramId=53
```

Now if my POST request body changes to

```
availableCostTypesReturn=1&availableCostTypesReturn=2&availableCostTypesReturn=3&
availableCostTypesReturn=4&availableCostTypesReturn=5&costTypeProgramId=53
```

then this method is not getting invoked.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/costTypes", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateCostType(
            Model model, 
            @RequestParam(value="availableCostTypesReturn")
            String[] availableCostTypesReturn,
            @RequestParam(value="selectedCostTypesReturn") 
            String[] selectedCostTypesReturn,
            @RequestParam(value="costTypeProgramId")
            int costTypeProgramId
        )
```

There are scenarios when only one of the availableCostTypesReturn, selectedCostTypesReturn parameter will be present.

Modified my method signature to this 
So how can i use the same method for this.

I am using Spring MVC 3.0.x

Modified my annotation signature as per answer from Tomasz Nurkiewicz

```
@RequestParam(value="availableCostTypesReturn", defaultValue= "", required = false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`required`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html#required%28%29) attribute of `@RequestParam` set to `false`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/costTypes", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateCostType(
            Model model, 
            @RequestParam(value="availableCostTypesReturn", required = false)
            String[] availableCostTypesReturn,
            @RequestParam(value="selectedCostTypesReturn", required = false) 
            String[] selectedCostTypesReturn,
            @RequestParam(value="costTypeProgramId", required = false)
            int costTypeProgramId
        )
```